# How to Create a Multi page form asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I'm fairly new to programming and the .net framework, I'm trying to create a registration page that would require users to move from one step to another. There would be a button at the bottom of each page that takes the user to the next page, however is there a way I can do this without haveing to create multiple pages. I've tried creating multiple forms in the asp.net page but i can't add server controls to the other forms as they don't have the attribute "runat='server'".

Please help, how do i go about it?

Comment: Try to search for [jQuery wizards in google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+wizard+steps)

Comment: You can look up the [ASP.NET Wizard Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

Comment: you could also look at the Wizard control which gives you much of what you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

Several ways you can accomplish this:

1. Put each section in its own `div` and use javascript to show/hide each section
2. Put each section in its own `asp:Panel` and show/hide each section on postback
3. Put each section in its own page and capture postback from previous page on the next page
4. Use the ASP.NET Wizard control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX

Comment: The javascript option is (in most cases) the best option here. The only difference I'd say is if you want to force the user to submit part of the data before other parts of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I really appreciate! Please @ElGavilan how do i use javascript to show/hide each section as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Something along the lines of `document.getElementById("idofcontainer").style.display = "none"` to hide or `"inline"`/`"block"` to show. You can also use jquery: `$("idofcontainer").hide()`, `$("idofcontainer").show()`, `$("idofcontainer").toggle()`

Comment: Thank you so much @Elgavilan. So I've succeded in hiding the divs until the user requests for them. Now the challenge is hiding the previous div once the current one is been displayed.  I'm currently using css and Javascript to hide the divs. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can get multiple page form facility.......
https://www.mindstick.com/forum/33822/how-to-use-jquery-steps-form-in-asp-dot-net

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to provide quality answers, it is usually recommended you include a code example. Do you think you could add that to your answer?